# Is it correct to use if else condition in laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, lumen

```
Route::get('/', function (){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return view('home');
    }
    else{
        return view('auth/login');
    }
```

or it is better with middleware to check if user is Auth

Comment: `return view(Auth::check() ? 'home' : 'auth/login');` Avoid if/else nesting whenever possible. But I think it is better to check in middleware to separate the logic.

Comment: That's work pretty good, Thanks a lot

Comment: You can wrap all your roures in the auth middleware, if an unauthorized person tries to access one of these sites, they will get redirect to the login page (or the page you specifiy) @skrrrr